# How to draw tangent line at a given point on the circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw this picture using *TikZ*. I'm almost done. After drawing K and the small circle I choose those 2 points (p and \tilde p). The problem is to draw the dashed circle containing those 2 points.

Also other problem is to draw the tangent lines T_1 and T_2. I've found some tricks to draw tangents to a curve but I don't have an open curve to use some positions (as path length).

Finally, how to draw the right angles? That is, the small square for right angles.

[image]

---

Here is my code for the moment. It's similar to the figure, it is not necessary to be exactly the same. Note that I had to do a trick to get the orthogonal circle.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (q) at (0,0);
\coordinate (t) at (-20:3cm);
\coordinate (t1) at (15:3.5cm);
\draw[name path=circ,fill=white!10] (q) circle (2cm); 
\draw[name path=reta] (q)--(t)node[below left]{$T$};
\path[name intersections={of=reta and circ,by={a}}] ;
\coordinate (o) at ($(a)!1cm!-90:(q)$);
\draw[name path=circ1] (o) circle (1cm);
\path[name intersections={of=circ and circ1,by={b}}] ;
\path[name path=linha,draw] (q)--(t1);
\path[name intersections={of=circ1 and linha,by={ztilde,z}}] ;

\draw (a) -- ($(a)!-4pt!(q)$) -- ($(a)!-4pt!(q)!4pt!90:(a)$) -- ($(a)!4pt!90:(q)$);
\draw (b) -- ($(b)!-4pt!(q)$) -- ($(b)!-4pt!(q)!4pt!-90:(b)$) -- ($(b)!4pt!-90:(q)$);

\draw[fill=white] (z)node[above left]{$z$} circle (1.2pt) (ztilde)node[above right]{$\tilde z$} circle (1.2pt) (a)node[below=2pt]{$a$} circle (1.2pt) (b)node[above=2pt]{$b$} circle (1.2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (q)node[left]{$q$} circle (1.2pt);
\node[below left] at (220:2cm){$\mathcal{K}$};
\node[right=1cm] at (o){$\mathcal{C}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It'd be easier if you include the code of what you have done so far

Comment: If you use the package [tkz-euclide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide) then right angles and tangents are commands available to you. The documentation is [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc) and the relevant part of the Altermundus site is [here](http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/euclide/index.html)

Comment: @DJP, I can not believe!!! Why did I find this before? Section 9.7.1 is exactly what I need. Inversion on circles.

Comment: I'm only just learning `tikz` myself.  (I usually use `pstricks`.)  I create a lot documents for geometry students.  I just recently found a nice package `tkz-euclide`.  You might want to check that out.